# Android start Activity 2 but rest at MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, show

I have MainActivity which has got a button that opens Activity 2. Everything from Activity 2 should be calculated and be run but the user should rest at MainActivity? How do I do this?

I found a solution where I dont run the "setContentView()" but then my app crashes.

Comment: what does it mean "but the user should rest at MainActivity?" ? explain more

Comment: are you sure that you don't just want to create a 2nd class that will run a certain code and return to your activity, instead of a 2nd activity?

Comment: Activity 2 shall start but user still shall see MainActivity with the buttons:

Comment: @MahmoudOmara I understand. But The second activity has a map and the map is called several times in the code. So I thought about playing the second activity in background but the user still sees MainActivity.
I am not sure if the code works when there is no map displayed

Comment: you should not include a map in the background like that, but to achieve this solution, u should look at using a Fragment instead of Activity for the map, and set the width/height to 0dp or the visibility to GONE

Comment: This is a good thought but it doesnt work. In .xml there is a blanc screen but when I start the app, the map is displayed normally

Comment: @MahmoudOmara visibility is gone but it opens still a new activity with blank screen

Comment: you shouldn't open a 2nd activity if you want the user to see the first, this entire thought is wrong from the start

Comment: But then I dont know how to realize my idea

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the view of application but does not want the user to change activity.

Use two different layout in xml file with id :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/first_view">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#358a32" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/second_view"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Then onclick of button :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    boolean firstViewOff = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        LinearLayout first_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_view);
        LinearLayout second_view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_view);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firstViewOff = true;
                first_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                second_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
    @override
    public void onBackPressed(){
      super.onBackPressed();
      if(firstViewOff){
        second_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        first_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        firstViewOff = false;
      }
    }

}
```

Why i attached backpressed :

Because when user backpress then it will just directly show firstview without closing,